# Hammerjs events order for nested elements

Tags: nested, event-handling, dom-events, hammer.js

Consider two nested divs with "click" event handlers:

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
parent.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("parent click");
});

var child = document.getElementById("child");
child.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("child click");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="parent" style="width:150px;height:100px;border: 1px solid black">
        <div id="child" style="width:75px;height:50px;border: 1px solid black"></div>
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

When one clicks on the nested element the "click" event "bubbles", so the output in the console looks like this:

> child click
>
> parent click

Now consider similar example with Hammerjs involved:

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var hammer1 = new Hammer(parent).on("tap", function() {
  console.log("parent click");
});

var child = document.getElementById("child");
var hammer2 = new Hammer(child).on("tap", function() {
  console.log("child click");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="parent" style="width:150px;height:100px;border: 1px solid black">
        <div id="child" style="width:75px;height:50px;border: 1px solid black">
        </div>
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

When one clicks on the nested element the console output is the opposite (parent's event handled first):

> parent click
>
> child click

To get the "bubble" event order one has to register child event handler before the parent's one.

Is there any way to achieve the same effect without messing with the order of event handler registrations?

Comment: Did you figure it out, finally?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I register event handlers in the reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, here's one trick I used successfully:

Normally you would do something like this:

```
$("some_selector").hammer().on('press', handlePress);
```

But to get the order right with Hammer events, this works:

```
$($("some_selector").get().reverse()).hammer().on('press', handlePress);
```

It's just a trick to get jQuery to assign the events in the reverse order (from the leaf children up the tree to the parents and parents parents etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this because I ran into the very same issue.

To understand the problem you need to know how hammerjs recognizes gestures (consisting of several events); in this case the "tap"-gesture.

Hammer installs so-called recognizers that get activated when certain events [travel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture) (bubble) along the DOM.

The "tap"-event gets triggered when the "pointerup"-event bubbles up to the `window`.
When the "pointerup"-event reaches the `window` (`event.currentTarget` is `window`) all registered recognizers get actived on that node's event and that is in the order of installation.

To respect the propagation line the "tap"-recognizer would have to fire on their respective element's "pointerup" event rather than on `window`.

Hope that is a somewhat consistent explanation.